# Wrong Vim syntax highlighting group in vim filetype

Tags: macos, vim, zsh, macvim, color-scheme

Hello to all Vim users,

I am running into a syntax color issue that I cannot solve: the `Plugin` word in my vimrc suddenly stopped being highlighted (colored) (see screenshot) for reasons that I cannot understand. I have this exact vimrc on another computer where the syntax coloring is working fine.

My configuration

- MacOS Mojave
- My shell emulator is `ZSH`
- I use Vim installed from MacVim (please note that I am not using the GUI provided by MacVim, I use vim in terminal)
- `$VIMRUNTIME = /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.2-166_1/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime`
- `colorscheme` set to default
- `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/vim.vim` is version 8.0-41 from the latest update of `MacVim` and I have not edited manually.
- vim version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Oct  7 2020 19:37:01)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-1719
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +cursorshape       +ipv6              -mouse_sysmouse    +ruby              +toolbar
+arabic            +dialog_con_gui    +job               +mouse_urxvt       +scrollbind        +transparency
+autocmd           +diff              +jumplist          +mouse_xterm       +signs             +user_commands
+autochdir         +digraphs          +keymap            +multi_byte        +smartindent       +vartabs
-autoservername    +dnd               +lambda            +multi_lang        -sound             +vertsplit
+balloon_eval      -ebcdic            +langmap           -mzscheme          +spell             +virtualedit
+balloon_eval_term +emacs_tags        +libcall           +netbeans_intg     +startuptime       +visual
+browse            +eval              +linebreak         +num64             +statusline        +visualextra
++builtin_terms    +ex_extra          +lispindent        +odbeditor         -sun_workshop      +viminfo
+byte_offset       +extra_search      +listcmds          +packages          +syntax            +vreplace
+channel           -farsi             +localmap          +path_extra        +tag_binary        +wildignore
+cindent           +file_in_path      +lua               +perl              -tag_old_static    +wildmenu
+clientserver      +find_in_path      +menu              +persistent_undo   -tag_any_white     +windows
+clipboard         +float             +mksession         +popupwin          +tcl               +writebackup
+cmdline_compl     +folding           +modify_fname      +postscript        +termguicolors     -X11
+cmdline_hist      -footer            +mouse             +printer           +terminal          -xfontset
+cmdline_info      +fork()            +mouseshape        +profile           +terminfo          +xim
+comments          +fullscreen        +mouse_dec         -python            +termresponse      -xpm
+conceal           +gettext           -mouse_gpm         +python3           +textobjects       -xsmp
+cryptv            -hangul_input      -mouse_jsbterm     +quickfix          +textprop          -xterm_clipboard
+cscope            +iconv             +mouse_netterm     +reltime           +timers            -xterm_save
+cursorbind        +insert_expand     +mouse_sgr         +rightleft         +title
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X -DMACOS
_X_DARWIN  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.
1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/l
ocal/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon
  -lm  -lncurses -liconv /usr/local/lib/libintl.a -framework AppKit  -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.3 -fstack-protecto
r  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl  -L/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.fr
amework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin -lpython3.9 -framework CoreFoundation -F/System/Library/Frameworks
 -framework Tcl -framework CoreFoundation -lruby.2.7
```

Can anyone help me on this please ?

Thank you very much,

Yoann

[image]

EDIT: This is the syntax highlighting I am trying to achieve.[image]

Comment: well first start could be starting vim with `vim -u NONE` and setting `:syntax on` afterwards. Does it work then? Then change the colorscheme to your colorscheme. Does it still work?

Comment: Hi @DoktorOSwaldo! I tried `vim -u NONE` and set `:syntax on` but it did not solve the issue (syntax highlighting is identical to the screenshot above). Regarding the colorscheme, it has always been the `default` for me. Out of curiosity - and to check if terminal coloring was not interfering- I tried the same on bash and on the default terminal of the Mac (on bash and zsh) but the result is always the same: `Plugin` word is not highlighted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well I haven't got any highlighting on the word `Plugin` either. So the question is not why you got it here, but why you have it on another computer. Try the same steps there. I would guess that with `vim -u NONE` you won't have the highlighting on the other computer either?

Comment: You are right there is actually no highligting on the word `Plugin`. What is wrong is the highlighting of what comes after. I checked the syntax groups with `:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")` on both computers. On the computer where the highlighting is wrong, the word `Plugin`, the string indicating the name of the plugin and the comment are all `vimUsrCmd`. On the computer where the highlighting is good, `Plugin` is `vimIsCommand`, the plugin name is `vimString` and the comment is `vimComment`. 

I need to figure out now why is the syntax group of `Plugin` wrongly set.

Comment: Btw, I edited the question to include a screenshot of what I would like to achieve. Best.

Comment: Ok I checked and I am in fact not using MacVim on the computer where the highlighting is good. I will try to reinstall vim from brew and remove MacVim (because I use vim only through CLI) to see if it solves the issue.